# How can I re-order <OL> based on screen size (bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a html  on my page. When the visitor's device is small it will show a single column with numbers increasing vertically.

When the visitor's device is medium width it will split these items into two columns by adding the class `col-md-6', but this gives me a horizontally orientated list of items, like this

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9
```

How can I get bootstrap instead to lay out the items like this for medium:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5
```

And like this for large:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Is this possible with CSS only (no JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS `columns` property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp), specially `column-count`.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ol>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>    
    </ol>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    ol {
        -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 2;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ol > li {
        margin: 0 2rem; /* This is needed in order to show the bullets */
    }
}

/* Large devices (tablets, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    ol {
        -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
```

#### Result

On medium devices
[image]

On large devices
[image]

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2dztLsvb/13/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can order your items using flexbox, but in order for them to wrap you need to explicitly set the height of the container to contain only the number of elements that you want in one column.

E.g. if you want to have 4 columns (each 20px high) you would have to set container's height to 80px.

```css
ol {
  height: 160px;
}

li {
  height: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ol {
    height: 100px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  ol {
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ol class="d-flex flex-column flex-wrap">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```